# Why Int32.Tryparse not returning correct values?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

```
int resultid;
Int32.TryParse(collection["id"],out resultid);
```

the values are coming in `collection["id"]` but resultid showing 0 for some of the values greater than 8 digit numbers. So that I tried with long also same issue ,getting `resultid` as `0`. Could please suggest?

Comment: What is the value of  `collection["id"]` exactly?

Comment: Posting an example of these values that cannot be parsed would be useful

Comment: Zero is default value for int, so it means you are putting wrong value and tryparse fails. It's why resultid is 0

Comment: Make sure that the number is in the correct format too. It's best if there's nothing but numbers (and a single minus sign if appropriate). The number could be formatted with thousands separators for example, which might require you to use culture dependent parsing or somesuch.

Comment: collection["Id"] values like 123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789,32112312312,12312312312 etc like that getting zero in out result varieable .

Answer (score 4):

TryParse returns true or false to indicate success. The value of the out parameter is used for the parsed value, or 0 on failure. So:

```
int value;
if (Int32.TryParse(someText, out value))
{
    // Parse successful. value can be any integer
}
else
{
    // Parse failed. value will be 0.
}
```

So if you pass in "0", it will execute the first block, whereas if you pass in "bad number" it will execute the second block.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't mentioned to use what is exactly `collection["id"]` but..

From [`Int32.TryParse Method (String, Int32)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> When this method returns, contains the 32-bit signed integer value
>   equivalent of the number contained in s, if the conversion succeeded,
>   **or zero if the conversion failed.**

Looks like your conversation fails because of your `collection["id"]` is bigger than `Int32.MaxValue` but since you didn't tell us more information, it is almost not possible to give exact answer..

`Int64` also has a [`TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zc2x2b1h%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method that I think it can hold your value like;

```
int resultid;
bool success = Int64.TryParse(collection["id"], out resultid);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
string s1 = "1234"; 
string s2 = "1234.65"; 
string s3 = null; 
string s4 = "123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789";


 success = Int32.TryParse(s1, out result); //-- success => true; result => 1234 
 success = Int32.TryParse(s2, out result); //-- success => false; result => 0 
 success = Int32.TryParse(s3, out result); //-- success => false; result => 0 
 success = Int32.TryParse(s4, out result); //-- success => false; result => 0
```

Comment: Nice examples, but a bit of context would have helped